# Flutter install updated apk downloaded

Tags: android, flutter, installation, apk

I want to run my update apk downloaded from my server to update my Flutter app when PlayStore is not available on an Android device.
There is a method to run a downloaded apk to install it?

I see the https://pub.dev/packages/install_plugin package that can be good for me but this conflict with other plugin used into my app.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [app_installer](https://pub.dev/packages/app_installer) plugin to install APK on Android.